# How to get substring to specific character

Tags: java, substring

Have specific substring like:

```
{"access_token":"TAeJxtzLtqwzAYQOG30WJkFFk3DxpCCKkhdUKdXcjSL2NqR0ayA3n7ZujQ0o7fGY4ZvbaESKuYw3XlJGbKc9w7FzCBPlBeMy4qj8yWk17j7OyKzCPoHeNUKkkIfTF_U1BFkdXTYqY4LJO9m21EXrvnDDnE6FHSgQbFgQRMhaeY1dLhXgDFsq93FqSvpKhR1gNEY71PkPPrFT-3pfybivPl1HS35tCZ63nftk17Kuw6l3lcwWRIj9HBLxT72_ulu74dP47Fz12CYcxrepb_RbTp2d7tAOkLEB1lYw2e3ddff00f03d82e9b36211220a974ae8b56c0263120c34a25a6c40c91a7f0fd","expires_in":179,"domain":"","username":"","firstname":"","lastname":"","email":"","roles":["","",""],"":true,"":
```

The length of token is dynamic , the same another fields. What I would like to do is extract substring `TAeJxtzLtqwzAYQOG30WJkFFk3DxpCCKkhdUKdXcjSL2NqR0ayA3n7ZujQ0o7fGY4ZvbaESKuYw3XlJGbKc9w7FzCBPlBeMy4qj8yWk17j7OyKzCPoHeNUKkkIfTF_U1BFkdXTYqY4LJO9m21EXrvnDDnE6FHSgQbFgQRMhaeY1dLhXgDFsq93FqSvpKhR1gNEY71PkPPrFT-3pfybivPl1HS35tCZ63nftk17Kuw6l3lcwWRIj9HBLxT72_ulu74dP47Fz12CYcxrepb_RbTp2d7tAOkLEB1lYw2e3ddff00f03d82e9b36211220a974ae8b56c0263120c34a25a6c40c91a7f0fd`

So as the second parameter of subString function must be provided something what identifies the first "," in this string. Anyone could help ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a JSON. Use JSON parser such as org.Json like this :

```
import org.json.*;


JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" your string ");
String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("pageInfo").getString("pageName");

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("access_token");
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use gson (or another library for JSON parsing) to parse this JSON String to object or to Map like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType(); //or use type of object of your JSON
Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(yourString, type); 
String accessToken = map.get("access_token");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is json check the other answers.

Else go for it with a matcher. for example:

```
    String regex = ".*access_token\":\"([^\"]+)\".*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    String data = "{\"access_token\":\"TAeJxtzLtqwzAYQOG30WJkFFk3DxpCCKkhdUKdXcjSL2NqR0ayA3n7ZujQ0o7fGY4ZvbaESKuYw3XlJGbKc9w7FzCBPlBeMy4qj8yWk17j7OyKzCPoHeNUKkkIfTF_U1BFkdXTYqY4LJO9m21EXrvnDDnE6FHSgQbFgQRMhaeY1dLhXgDFsq93FqSvpKhR1gNEY71PkPPrFT-3pfybivPl1HS35tCZ63nftk17Kuw6l3lcwWRIj9HBLxT72_ulu74dP47Fz12CYcxrepb_RbTp2d7tAOkLEB1lYw2e3ddff00f03d82e9b36211220a974ae8b56c0263120c34a25a6c40c91a7f0fd\",\"expires_in\":179\",";

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    if(matcher.matches())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

The regex ".*access_token\":\"([^\"]+)\".*" basically means match anything access_token":"(not a ")" anything.

If it is performance critical do the pattern compile static as it is a quite expensive operation.